# Best Way To Check If Booking Slot is Available in MySQL database tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have my database and table structure in place now for my booking system. I now need to be able to search to see if a certain car is available during a set of dates. My table structure is:

car_table: (stores car info)

```
ID     | car_make | car_name
1      | Ford     | Focus
2      | BMW      | Z3
3      | Audi     | A5
```

booking_table: (stores majority of info - dates, id etc)

```
booking_ID  | start_date | end_date
125674      | 2013-02-27 | 2013-03-01    
887463      | 2013-03-05 | 2013-03-07     
209930      | 2013-03-16 | 2013-03-22
```

reservation_table: (links the car to the booking)

```
ID     | booking_ID | car_ID
1      | 125674     | 2
2      | 887463     | 2
3      | 209930     | 1
```

With PDO PHP what is the best search query to do to make sure that only the available dates show up as bookable as I need to make sure I don't get duplicate bookings/dates. At the moment all I can think of is searching for any bookings during the customers requested dates like so, if I get any results back then it means it's not available otherwise I can proceed:

```
$query_params = array( 
   ':start_search' => $_POST['user_selected_startdate'],
    ':end_search' => $_POST['user_selected_enddate'],
);

$query = " 
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        booking_table
    WHERE 
        start_date BETWEEN :start_search AND :end_search AND
        end_date BETWEEN :start_search AND :end_search 
"; 

try { 
    $stmt = DB::get()->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute($query_params); 

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
}  
catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

if(!$rows) {
    // booking is available, continue and pay
}
else {
    // booking is unavailable, try again
}
```

Is this the best procedure and more secure way of making sure no-one books over another slot?

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with php OR pdo. how you interface with the db or from which language you're doing it is irrelevant. You just need to figure out the actual SQL query. That will remain constant regardless of the host language/interface library.

Comment: You are not passing $ query_parms to query .

Comment: You may use select count(1) instead of retrieving all rows

Comment: @CarlosGant i replaced mySELECT * with SELECT count(1) and i am getting no rows even when i should be, do i need to alter anything else in the code? I appreciate the help with my my code but in response to the first few comments - i just want to know if that is the best search query to use for such a task or whether just searching if a row is not present is the most reliable way?

Comment: Try `WHERE  start_date >= :start_search AND end_date <= :end_search`